# How to connect to a HTTPS proxy (secure web proxy) in pycurl?

Tags: curl, proxy, pycurl

I'm trying to connect to a [secure web proxy](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy) with pycurl. When trying to set the appropriate proxy type, these options are available, which correspond to the curl proxy options (in brackets):

```
 - "PROXYTYPE_HTTP" (CURLPROXY_HTTP)
 - "PROXYTYPE_HTTP_1_0" (CURLPROXY_HTTP_1_0)
 - "PROXYTYPE_SOCKS4" (CURLPROXY_SOCKS4)
 - "PROXYTYPE_SOCKS4A" (CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A)
 - "PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5" (CURLPROXY_SOCKS5)
 - "PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME" (CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME)
```

But, there's also a curl option called `CURLPROXY_HTTPS`, as stated in the [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.html), that does not seem to be available.

With plain curl, I use this command to connect to the proxy:

```
curl --proxy https://proxy-host:proxy-port --proxy-insecure -U username:password https://target.com
```

And everything just works as expected. But not with pycurl.

How can I achieve the same behavior in pycurl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [suggestion](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/622) I got in the pycurl github issues, I've found the option code for CURLPROXY_HTTPS, and it is `2`.

I was able to make a request through a secure web proxy with pycurl using the next code:

```py
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO
import certifi


def request_with_pycurl(username, password, host, port, target_url='https://api.ipify.org/'):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()

    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())

    # set proxy-insecure
    c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)

    # set headers
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')

    # set proxy
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, f"https://{host}:{port}")

    # proxy auth
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERPWD, f"{username}:{password}")

    # set proxy type = "HTTPS"
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, 2)

    # target url
    c.setopt(c.URL, target_url)

    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
    c.perform()
    c.close()

    body = buffer.getvalue()
    return body


response = request_with_pycurl("proxy_username", "proxy_password", "proxy_host", "proxy_port").decode()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Anybody else came for crawlera proxy or proxy without password if above answer does not works, here is an update of [Andriy Stolyar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61311821/471376),

```python
def request_with_pycurl(username, password, host, port, target_url='http://api.ipify.org/'):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()

    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())

    # set proxy-insecure
    c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)

    # set headers
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')

    # set proxy
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, f"http://{host}:{port}")

    # proxy auth
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERNAME, username)

    # set proxy type = "HTTPS"
    #c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, 2)

    # target url
    c.setopt(c.URL, target_url)

    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
    c.perform()
    c.close()

    body = buffer.getvalue()
    return body


response = request_with_pycurl("KEY:", "", "HOST", "PORT").decode()

print(response)
```